# How to inject Github secret as environment variable into Maven settings.xml file run in a Dockerfile?

Tags: maven, dockerfile, docker-secrets

I have a Github action `docker/build-push-action@v3` with a secret that I want to make available in my Dockerfile.

The following is my github action docker/build-push-action config:

```
 - name: Build Docker image and push to ghcr.io registry
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ghcr.io/katlock/myimage:latest
          secrets: |
            GIT_AUTH_TOKEN=${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
            PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN=${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
            IMAGEREGISTRY=HelloMan
```

I want to make `PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN` variable with its value accessible in my Dockerfile.   When I run my maven command in the Dockerfile I want it to be available for the settings.xml as you will see below.

However, the PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN seems to be empty.  I tried printing out the IMAGEREGISTRY secret which contains a dummy value and is always empty in my Dockerfile instruction.

My Dockerfile runs using the github action with the following:

```
FROM maven:3-openjdk-17-slim as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY pom.xml settings.xml ./
COPY src ./src
RUN echo ${IMAGEREGISTRY}
RUN echo "imageRegistry is : ${IMAGEREGISTRY}"
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=IMAGEREGISTRY \
    echo "imageRegistry: ${IMAGEREGISTRY}, $IMAGEREGISTRY"
RUN echo "imageRegistry: ${IMAGEREGISTRY}"
RUN ["mvn",  "-s",  "settings.xml", "clean", "install"]
```

The settings.xml has this variable $PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN that I want injected:

```
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>github</id>
            <username>katlock</username>
            <password>${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're able to specify properties along with your Maven goal.

```
RUN ["mvn",  "-s",  "settings.xml", "clean", "install", "-Dgithub.token=TOKEN_GOES_HERE"]
```

And on `pom.xml`, you can use this to pick up the token.

```
<password>${github.token}</password>
```